# Checking subset of data in 2nd table if one of subset is true the condition is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

[image]

```sql
SELECT [O].[ID], 
       LI1.OrderID, 
       [LI1].[IsComplete], 
       [O].[CustomerID], 
       [O].[CustomerPO]               AS [PurchaseOrderNumber], 
       [O].[OrderNumber]              AS [SalesOrderNumber], 
       CAST([O].[ShipDate] AS DATE)   AS [expectedShipDate], 
       CAST([O].[InHandDate] AS DATE) AS [expectedDeliveryDate], 
       o.InvoicedFromID 
FROM   dbo.Orders [O] WITH (NOLOCK) 
       INNER JOIN dbo.LineItems LI1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
               ON O.ID = LI1.OrderID 
                  AND o.InvoicedFromID = 56 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   dbo.LINEITEMS LI2 WITH (NOLOCK) --  
                   WHERE  LI1.OrderID = LI2.OrderID 
                          AND LI2.IsComplete = 0)
```

Comment: Can you share your output?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query -

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Orders [O] WITH (NOLOCK) 
     INNER JOIN dbo.LineItems LI1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                ON O.ID = LI1.OrderID 
                AND o.InvoicedFromID = 56
WHERE LI1.InvoiceID IN (SELECT InvoiceID
                        FROM dbo.LineItems
                        GROUP BY Iscomplete, InvoiceID
                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Iscomplete = 1 THEN 1 END) >= 1
```